# Reactのmaterial-ui-pickersのTimePickerの時間表記を変更したい

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

お世話になります。
ReactでTimePickerを使用していて時間の表記を00:00~23:59ではなく、05:00~28:59に変更したいのですが実装例をご教示きいただけませんでしょうか。

※イメージ

**現状:**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**期待値**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 残念ながら、material-ui-pickersにそのような機能は搭載されていないようです。（[開始時間と終了時間はここでべた書きされている](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/material-ui-pickers/blob/develop/lib/src/TimePicker/components/ClockNumbers.tsx#L18)。）　どうしてもその機能が必要なら、material-ui-pickersを自分で改造する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。改造するかUIを変更するか検討してみます。